# jquery event help

Tags: jquery, events

I have a setup like this:

```
    <div id="container">
       <div id="close">Close</div>
    </div>
```

Then in my jquery I have this:

```
$("#container").live("click",function(){
   changeTabs();
});

$("#close").live("click", function(){
   closeTabs();
});
```

The problem with that is that when you click the close div it fires both events. I am guessing it is because the second div overlays the first one. So how can I cancel or stop the first event from firing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.stopPropagation.28.29)

From [the jQuery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.stopPropagation.28.29):

> Stops the bubbling of an event to
>   parent elements, preventing any parent
>   handlers from being notified of the
>   event.

In your case, this might look like

```
$("#close").live("click", function(evt){
   evt.stopPropagation();
   closeTabs();
});
```

Comment: +1 spot on, also, `return false` will stopPropagation and preventDefault (in a jQuery event handler).

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
$("#container:not(#close)").live("click",function(){
   changeTabs();
});

$("#close").live("click", function(){
   closeTabs();
});
```

Using the [not selecto](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/not#selector)r.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want to use a div as a close click event, are you okay to use an input button instead?

```
<div id="container">
       <input type="button" id="close" value="Close"/>
</div>

$("#container").live("click",function(){
    changeTabs();
});

$("#close").live("click", function(){
    closeTabs();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok so the method that worked was under the closeTabs() function I did return false; and that seemed to fix it